# How to iterate over dataframe rows, replacing values from a matching tuple in a more pythonic way?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, optimization

I am able to replace values in a specific column of a pandas dataframe by iterating over the rows, and match these values to the corresponding tuple pairs which are contained in a list of tuples.

However, when I run this code on a large dataframe, it becomes relatively slow as it has to iterate over the entire list of tuples to find a match for the row in the dataframe.
(12280it [23:21,  8.66it/s])

Is there a more pythonic way to do the matching and replacing? For example indexing the list of tuples, and a bit of code that filters by index?

My used code can be found below.

```
import pandas as pd 
from tqdm import tqdm

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['some', 1], ['random', 10], ['stuff', 14],['which',8],['is',22],['irrelevant',24]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Strings', 'Number'])
```

```
df
    Strings     Number
0   some         1
1   random       10
2   stuff        14
3   which        8
4   is           22
5   irrelevant   24
```

```
#Create lists necessary to make tuples
x = list(range(1, 25))
y = list(range(345, 395, 2))

#Create tuple
z = list(zip(x,y))

#Replace number values in dataframe
#With corresponding values from tuple
for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows()):
    for x in z:
        if row["Number"] ==x[0]:
            df.set_value(index,"Number", int(x[1]))
```

results in

```
df
    Strings     Number
0   some        345
1   random      363
2   stuff       371
3   which       359
4   is          387
5   irrelevant  391
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`

```
z = dict(zip(x,y))
df['Number'] = df['Number'].map(z)
```

---

```
      Strings  Number
0        some     345
1      random     363
2       stuff     371
3       which     359
4          is     387
5  irrelevant     391
```

---

To map only *some* values and avoid `NaN`, use `replace`

```
df['Number'] = df['Number'].replace(z)
```